# Register WooCommerce new product type within a class

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api, woocommerce-subscriptions, woocommerce-bookings

This is the action that registers a new product type in woocomerce:

```
// Register product type
add_action( 'init', 'register_new_product_type' );
function register_new_product_type() {

    class WC_Product_Demo extends WC_Product {  
      
        public function __construct( $product ) {
            $this->product_type = 'the_new_type';
            parent::__construct( $product );
        }

    }

}
```

I am trying to wrap this action in class like this:

```
// Register product type
class __register_product_type{

    function __construct(){
        add_action( 'init', array( $this, 'register_new_product_type' ) );      
    }
    
    function register_new_product_type() {

        class WC_Product_Demo extends WC_Product {   
     
            public function __construct( $product ) {
                $this->product_type = 'the_new_type';
                parent::__construct( $product );
            }

        }

    }

}
```

But it is throwing a fatal error.
How could I wrap the registration action inside the class?

Answer (score 0):

Class declarations can't be nested. So you can't declare a class inside of another class. Your question/example isn't quite clear why you need the `__register_product_type` class in the first place. All it seems to do is try to setup the `WC_Product_Demo` class. Either just use the `WC_Product_Demo` class and call it after declaring it.

```
if ( !class_exists( 'WC_Product_Demo' ) ) {
    class WC_Product_Demo extends WC_Product {   

        public function __construct( $product ) {
            $this->product_type = 'the_new_type';
            parent::__construct( $product );
        }

    }
}
new WC_Product_Demo();
```

Or if you have to call it from the `__register_product_type` class, create a separate file to setup the `WC_Product_Demo` class, and use `include_once()` to call it.

```
if ( !class_exists( '__register_product_type' ) ) {
    class __register_product_type {   

        public function __construct( $product ) {
            include_once( 'PATH TO YOUR WC PRODUCT DEMO HERE' );

        }
    }
}
```